# Pass Objects To Directive From Html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive with isolate scope that receives items from its parent:

```
scope: {
  items: '=?items'
}
```

For example, if I have:

```
$scope.items = [
  {id: 1, description: 'foo'},
  {id: 2, description: 'bar'},
]
```

I can pass it like so:

```
<my-directive items = "items"></my-directive>
```

The problem is that I don't always have the items packaged neatly into an object and there are situations where I want to pass random data. For example:

```
<my-directive items = "[ {id: 5, description: {{someScopeVar.someTextProp}}} ]"></my-directive-items>
```

The code above does not work. Is it possible to do? Is it ABSOLUTELY horrible practice?

Edit: I just added a new variable on the parent scope which packages what I need into an object wrapped in an array (because directive takes array). This is a purely theoretical question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

```
<my-directive items = "[ {id: 5, description: {{someScopeVar.someTextProp}}} ]"></my-directive-items>
```

To:

```
<my-directive items = "[ {id: 5, description: someScopeVar.someTextProp} ]"></my-directive-items>
```

Comment: Hmm, guessed I missed the obvious while assuming it won't work, thanks.

Comment: If my answer is right for you, please `up vote` and `accept`. If not you can `down vote`

Comment: lol, I might have to downvote now just for the comment within 5 minutes + after it's accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 0):

you can get random object with function

```
scope: {
  items: '&'
}
```

in controller

```
$scope.items = [
  {id: 1, description: 'foo'},
  {id: 2, description: 'bar'},
]

$scope.getRandom = function(){
     // do something here ( wrap object in array, get random object etc)
     // return $scope.myWrapedObject
}
```

.

```
<my-directive items = "getRandom()"></my-directive>
```

Comment: That's not what I am going for at all.

Comment: update my answer. You can do anything inside function

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I understand how to wrap objects via a function. The problem was that the wrapper solution wasn't optimal for me and I wanted to do it from html in this instance.